# When to use any of <video> and <iframe> to embed video

Tags: html

We can embed video on our webpage using `<video>` and `<iframe>` tags. When is one expected to use either of them?

Answer (score 1):

### [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

> The  tag specifies an inline frame.
>
> An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current
>   HTML document.

You don't use an iframe, to display your own video, but to display a video (or document) hosted on an external website.

Use [video](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_video.asp) if you want to display (embed) the video in your own website.